# Measuring Distances

Tags: matlab

I tried to find the distances shown in the figure with matlab but I just get the distances between the black bollards. I don't know what I have to do to get the distance for the white space too.

I used the following code:

```
clc;                              
clear all;                        
close all;                        
imtool close all;                 
workspace;
I = [values of data];
findpeaks(I,'MinPeakProminence',4,'Annotate','extents')
[pks,locs,widths,proms] = findpeaks(I);
text(locs+.02,pks,num2str((1:numel(pks))'))
```

[image]
widths

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
% example data 
xx = [repmat(50,1,5), repmat(250,1,7), repmat(50,1,8), repmat(250,1,4), repmat(50,1,6), repmat(250,1,9), repmat(50,1,9), repmat(250,1,4)];

%plot the data 
figure 
plot(xx)

% for this method you need to define a threshold which ideally deliminates 
% peaks from troughs 
trsh = 150;

% Find the distances between the waveforms 
diff(find(abs(diff(xx > trsh))))
```

> ans =
>
> ```
>  7     8     4     6     9     9
> ```

[image]